# Preparing a Windows XP development environment for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, windows-xp

I am trying to get started with MS Sharepoint.

How can I prepare my Standalone PC (running Windows XP Professional) to have a development environment for MS Sharepoint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, you want to build a virtual machine.  For more specific details on how to setup a SharePoint developer virtual machine, see this [post](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/04/07/building-a-windows-server-2008-moss-virtual-machine.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Download and Install [Virtual Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/virtualserver/downloads.aspx)

Next download the [VHD](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74) and get it hooked to the Virtual Server, noting more, you are ready to go.

Comment: Note that it is time-bombed to 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be on ServerFault...hence the close votes.

But while it is here I will give some suggestions.  Get virtual pc up and running on your XP box.  Install a windows 2003 image on that VPC.  Then install sharepoint in there.  Then you have something to develop against.

Comment: Don't forget about the database...
When installing SharePoint, you will be asked to select either standalone or "regular" (I forget the exact wording) mode. If you select standalone, the install will install and configure SQL Server Express. However if you are not going to do standalone then you are going to need to have a SQL Server database setup and an account that has create database rights will need to be provided to the SharePoint installer.